# Fast way to numerically compute smallest non-zero singular value for implicit matrix A

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ implicitly defined (i.e. for which I can calculate the matrix-vector products $Ax$ and $A^T x$, but storing the entire matrix is prohibitive in terms of memory).

What is a fast numerical algorithm to only compute the smallest non-zero singular value for $A$?
Note that memory requirements for the algorithm should be $O(m+n)$, since storing the entire matrix is not feasible.

Comment: Some kind of [inverse iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration) might be a good way to go

Comment: Can it be assumed that $A$ has maximal rank $\min\{m,n\}$? If not, is the rank of $A$ known in advance?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes maximal rank can be assumed. For what concerns inverse iteration, I've already seen it, but I don't understand how I'm assumed to solve the system $AA^T x = b$ by simply knowing how to multiply by $A$...

Comment: You're right; I was thinking of multiplying by $(A^TA)^{-1}$, but that doesn't really work using multiplication by $A$ and $A^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I'll post it as an answer. What you're hoping to do is very challenging. Part of the reason power iteration and its cousins work so well is that iterative multiplications by a symmetric matrix converge very quickly to the dominant eigenvectors, making the small eigenvectors very challenging to find just by multiplications.

The best algorithm I can think of is to, as Ben Grossmann suggested, do inverse iteration to compute the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ and then take square roots. Linear systems of the form $(A^\top A)x = b$ can then be solved by the conjugate gradient method. Each inverse iteration loop requires $\mathcal{O}(M\kappa(A) \log(1/\epsilon))$ operations where $M$ is the time to multiply by $A$ and $A^\top$, $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$, and $\epsilon$ is the accuracy desired for the CG solves. Then you'll need something like $\mathcal{O}(\log (1/\epsilon)/\log(\sigma_1(A)/\sigma_2(A)))$ iterations to achieve accuracy $\epsilon$. My sense is that it's hard to do better than this, but I hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: What would be the required precision in the solution of the linear system $(A^T A)x = b$ at the $n$-th step of the inverse iteration? I guess that at the start these systems require to be solved more lazily than in successive steps.

Moreover, why would conjugate gradient be better than Arnoldi iterations or GMMRES?
Does there exist Nesterov-like accelerated conjugate gradient methods, to get $O(\sqrt{\kappa(A)})$?

Comment: @trenta3 I'm not aware of the optimal precision to solve the normal equations for use in an eigenvalue algorithm. If you're going to solve to only modest accuracy, it might be worth using a method like Jacobi-Davidson which is explicitly designed to use an inexact linear solve. If you're going to solve the normal equations which are symmetric positive definite, then I believe conjugate gradient is the best there is: GMRES and Nesterov-accelerated gradient methods are less effective. There might be other approaches than using the normal equations...

Comment: ...but these might require more iterations for your eigenvalue algorithm depending on how well separated the eigenvalues of the matrix are. The best tradeoff of those considerations I can come up with is conjugate gradient applied to $A^\top A$. I would be delighted to see a better approach if one exists.